# Ruby Rescue exception not firing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, exception, rescue

> Ruby 2.3.7p456
>   Rails 5.2.2
>   iMac macOS Mojave v 10.14.3

The code segment below triggers an **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound** error at **@cart = Cart.find(nil)** but the rescue block never fires off.

Thanks for your help, please let me know if there is anything else I need to provide.

```
 module CurrentCart
  private
  def set_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(nil)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    puts 'There was an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error'
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the result of running this code then? Is the exception thrown out of this method?

Comment: can you try adding the line `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` at the beginning of the method and see if that is caught?

Comment: You can improve your question by telling where, when and how's that behavior happening.

Comment: Could you try `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound unless Cart.find(nil)` ?

Comment: @mrzasa What happens is, the error is thrown and everything stops and the web browser complains that there is an error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound. From what I understand, rescue is supposed to catch that error just like a try/catch block would in other languages like Javascript.

Comment: @UpvoteMe raising an error raises an error and is also not caught by the rescue

Comment: @SebastianPalma well...it's in a rails project but I'm a total newb and idk how to answer.... but, in this case the problem appears to be a syntax related error independent of rails. the rescue is just not catch the error specified.

Comment: @zeitnot Yes and same result. The error is thrown and the whole thing dies. The rescue block never fires.

Comment: The project I am working on is out of the Agile Web Development with Rails 5.1 book. I've been following it carefully and this error is just a weird thing that I can't seem to answer myself. A coworker of mine had me install a different version of ruby via rbenv and this seems to have fixed the problem. But it still doesn't explain what the actual issue was. I'm at a loss, but I would like to thank everyone for their help :)

Comment: Just remove `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` and leave `rescue` keyword alone.

Comment: That's not recommendable @zeitnot.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Yes, I know but my aim was just to debug the rescue section.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a different version of Ruby via RBENV seems to have fixed the problem, I couldn't tell you why this worked except that the code may have been intended for a specific version of Ruby.